# Error near the keyword 'Set' when trying to submite a while for data generate propose

Tags: sql-server-2008

[image]

I get this error but i don't have any idea how to solve this issue, i'm trying to run this script on Dbeaver it's a simply query but i try to look at all sources i could and dont get any answer, even on the dbeaver foruns.

The script is pretty basic, and the table has only 2 fields Id and Description it's just for pagination test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer just by switching the "Id" for "Counter", maybe DBeaver treats the word "Id" in some different mode than others managers.